# Check for nullable datetime

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF C# project.

I have a DateTime control named `dtBookingDate`

If some date value is selected inside `dtBookingDate` then I want to execute some code. I tried the following (See screenshot)

[image: error1 shown by visual studio]

```
if (dtBookingDate.SelectedDate.HasValue)
{
   tempResult = tempResult.Where(x => x.BookingDate.Date == dtBookingDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date);
}
```

Even though `HasValue` property returns `false` still control goes inside `if block`.

[image: error2 shown by visual studio]

```
if (dtBookingDate.SelectedDate != null)
{
   tempResult = tempResult.Where(x => x.BookingDate.Date == dtBookingDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date);
}
```

Even though `SelectedDate` property is `null` still control goes inside `if block`.

**StackTrace (Just 1 line)**

```
   at TransportApp.Views.HomeScreen.PackageTracking.SearchQuery.TrackPackage() in D:\ESCENER\Repo\TransportApp\TransportApp\Views\HomeScreen\PackageTracking\SearchQuery.xaml.cs:line 59
```

Please some one explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Please post code instead of or along with screen shot.

Comment: Note that `Where` is lazy evaluated, so it will not evaluate that until later when the captured value is `null`.

Comment: @juharr: posted code. My question is not related to code but related to the behavior of Visual Studio. Even tough HasValue returns false still the control is going inside if block

Comment: The code doesn't equal the screenshot; the screenshot checks `HasValue`

Comment: please let me know if anything more from the code is required?

Comment: I'm curious... what happens if you just make a new DateTime var and save dtBookingDate.SelectedDate.Value in that, and then use that local var in the call to `Where`?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?  It's currently obscured by the exception pop-up in your screen shot.

Comment: @Nyerguds: let me know if my understanding is correct... I should create a new DateTime var, copy SelectedDate inside new var and then check against it?

Comment: @NileshBarai I suggest trying that, yes. Save its value into a normal non-nullable DateTime before the linq thing. Then you're sure it can't be null, and nothing can affect it during the search.

Comment: @Nyerguds: In once sense that's correct but as dtBookingDate is a DateTime control present on form and it depends on user whether to select a value or not inside it and selecting a value should not be mandatory that's by requirement.

Comment: No, no. Make that DateTime var _inside_ the if-check's brackets. Right after you checked the `HasValue`.

Answer (score -1):

I think there's some bug in Visual Studio 2015. I changed Solution Configuration from Release to Debug and everything started working fine.